# correct mysql syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

please could someone tell me the problem with this syntax because mysql 5.5.32 keeps tell me about an error

```
CREATE TABLE `clients` (
    `ID` tinyint(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `title` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
    `firstName` varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
    `lastName` varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
    `address1` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
    `address2` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
    `town` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
    `province` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
    `country` varchar(40) NOT NULL default '',
    `postCode` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
    `telephone` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
    `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
    `cardNo` varchar(16) NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
    `expiryDate` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
    PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) TYPE=MyISAM COMMENT='customer table' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: I tried his question. And error message was `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM COMMENT='customer table' AUTO_INCREMENT=1' at line 17`

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM COMMENT='customer table' AUTO_INCREMENT=1' at line 31

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `TYPE` has been replaced by `ENGINE` as in

```
ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Answer (score 1):

change `TYPE` to `ENGINE` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `clients` (
    `ID` tinyint(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `title` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
    `firstName` varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
    `lastName` varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
    `address1` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
    `address2` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
    `town` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
    `province` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
    `country` varchar(40) NOT NULL default '',
    `postCode` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
    `telephone` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
    `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
    `cardNo` varchar(16) NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
    `expiryDate` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
    PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM COMMENT='customer table' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

MySQL 5.0 accepts `TYPE` or `ENGINE`, but above MySQL 5.1, Only `ENGINE` is allowed.